# mysql order by hour starting from 22:00

Tags: mysql, time, hour

I have a table with a time field. The time format is HH:mm.
The hours only go from 22:00 to 06:00.
I want to sort the rows so they look like this:

```
Hour
22:00
22:30
23:15
00:15
01:30
03:50
05:30
```

But in my current query:

```
select * from events order by hour
```

they look like this:

```
Hour
00:15
01:30
03:50
05:30
22:00
22:30
23:15
```

Is it possible? thanks!

Comment: ORDER BY with case `SELECT 
 EVENTS.Hour
FROM 
 EVENTS
ORDER BY
   CASE
      WHEN
        HOUR(EVENTS.Hour) >= 22
      THEN
       0
      ELSE
       1
   END
   ` or ORDER BY with IF `SELECT 
 EVENTS.Hour
FROM 
 EVENTS
ORDER BY
   IF (
        HOUR(EVENTS.Hour) >= 22
      , 0
      , 1
   )
   ` using the HOUR function is somehow more clean then using SUBSTR function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    events
ORDER BY CASE
    WHEN SUBSTR(hour, 1, 2) >= '22' THEN 0
    ELSE 1
END , hour;
```